# CMake: Is it possible to run CONFIGURE_FILE after each make?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I've got the following piece of script in my CMake file:

```
CONFIGURE_FILE(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.hpp.cmake
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.hpp
)
```

But it's only run after executing `cmake`, not `make`. Is it possible to create the `version.hpp` file after each make?

Here is the content of `version.hpp.cmake`:

```
#ifndef _VERSION_HPP_
#define _VERSION_HPP_

#define MAJOR_VERSION "${MAJOR}"
#define MINOR_VERSION "${MINOR}"
#define PATCH_VERSION "${PATCH}"
#define RELEASE_VERSION "${RELEASE}"

#endif //_VERSION_HPP_
```

The `MAJOR`, `MINOR`, `PATCH` and `RELEASE` variables have been defined in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

P.S. [This post](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-May/050221.html) is apparently related to my question, but I can't get a grasp of it.

Comment: What is inside of `version.hpp.cmake`? If you specify version macros in `CMakeLists.txt`, then invoking `make` would lead to check if `CMakeLists.txt` has been changed and it would invoke `cmake` automatically.

Comment: @yegorich `cmake` is currently invoked if `CMakeLists.txt` file has changed. But what if the `version.hpp` does not exist (for some reason), how would it be created?

Comment: What if you add version.hpp to your add_executable()?

Comment: @yegorich didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `configure_file` is supposed to run at configure time, that is when you run `cmake`, instead of compile time, which is when you run  `make`. There is no easy way around this.

The problem is that the information written by `configure_file` is dependent on variables from the CMake build environment. Changes to those variables cannot be detected without running CMake again. If you have that information mirrored somewhere else, you can use a custom command to extract it and perform the code generation for you, as [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21671716/577603) suggested.

The approach suggested in the [post from the CMake mailing list that you linked](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-May/050221.html) in your answer is based on a two-phase CMake run: The outer CMake project (which is run only once) adds a custom build step for building the inner CMake project (which is then run with every `make`) where the `configure_file` is performed. The underlying idea is the same as with Peter's answer, only instead of a Python script you use a CMake script for generating the file.

My personal recommendation: For a simple problem as a version header, I would not bother with such a complicated approach. Simply generate the file to your BINARY_DIR (not to your project dir, as you currently do! you want to retain the ability to do several out-of-source builds from the same source) and assume that it will be there for compilation. If a user is brave enough to mess with the generated files there, they can be expected to re-run CMake on their own.

Answer (score 3):

So I accidentally stumbled across this, I know it is probably too late, but calling configure is possible an exactly how I do this with mercurial versions.

The trick requires a lot of different tools, and I don't have time to formulate into a good answer atm, but ask questions and I'll fill it in when I have time.

tool 1: calling exec_program to extract the revision information (this is really easy with mercurial)

```
exec_program(hg ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ARGS "id" "-i" OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_HASH_CODE)
```

I'm probably doing something more complicated than you care about here, but the essential bit is `hg` which you'll replace with whatever version control you are using, `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` which you'll set to whatever executing directory you want, and fill in the custom args.

I put all of the version extraction into a single macro (`ReadProjectRevisionStatus()`).

The next step is to make a an entirely different CMake file that calls ReadProjectRevisionStatus() and then CONFIGURE_FILE. This file will assume that all the correct values are set when you come into it. In my case, I store the location of this file into ${CONFIG_FILE_LOC}.

The final step is to add a custom target that will call this script. For example:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_VERSION_CONFIG
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    ARGS -DPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    -DPROJECT_BINARY_DIR=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    -DPROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
    "-D${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_CONFIG_FILE_IN=\"${${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_CONFIG_FILE_IN}\""
    "-D${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_CONFIG_FILE_OUT=\"${${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_CONFIG_FILE_OUT}\""
    ${ARGN}
    -P ${CONFIG_FILE_LOC})
```

One of the beauties of doing it this way is that custom target call can still be called outside of a cmake build system, which I've done on a couple of projects, which a bash call similar to:

```
cmake -D PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR=$sourcedir -DPROJECT_BINARY_DIR=$sourcedir -DPROJECT_NAME=uControl -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$sourcedir -DuControl_HG_CONFIG_FILE_IN=$sourcedir/tsi_software_version.h.in -DuControl_HG_CONFIG_FILE_OUT=$sourcedir/tsi_software_version.h -P $sourcedir/ConfigureHGVersion.cmake
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was still waiting for a proper answer to this question. I will look into your answer and will ask further questions if anything is not clear. I hope I can get it working.

Comment: What is the value of `${Files}`?

Comment: `CONFIGURE_FILE` is executed only when its input file has changed. Where do you update the input file?

Comment: @Meysam I think you misunderstand. The custom target calls a cmake script which calls configure_file. A custom target will be called on every iteration and thus will be called every time. That DEPENDS statement may be erroneous...

Answer (score 1):

One possibity is to generate version.hpp from Python and use [ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command)

```
... find python ...
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(gen_version ALL ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} gen_version.py)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(version.hpp PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)
... link gen_version to your library/executable ...
```

Comment: Thank you. What's the content of `gen_version.py`? Could you please give a more detailed answer?

Comment: @Meysam This is really very basic of Python, read tutorial http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ and use datetime http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html